# Eclipse yellow dot symbol

Tags: java, eclipse, facelets

*Using:* Eclipse, JSF, Facelets.

```
<h:message for="loginButton">
```

This tag is used outside the form which contains the actual UIComponend named *loginButton*. When I use eclipse suggest the for attribute is marked this way: [image: yellow dot].
What does the yellow dot stands for?

**LE:**

I tried [here](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm) but I couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, it means required attribute.